# Countdown timer's speed increases as I press start and pause button one after another for few times in tkinter

Tags: python, windows, tkinter

I have a countdown script where seconds updates quickly as I press start and pause button few times one after another.

At first I thought clicking quickly between start and pause buttons speeds the seconds so I added `time.sleep(1)` to delay click between the buttons which didn't worked.

**How can I fix this problem?**

**Is my algorithm correct? Or Is there other better way to make the countdown time? If yes, how can I do it?**

**CODE**

```
from tkinter import *

PAUSE = False
HOUR, MINUTE, SECOND = 0, 0, 0


def start():
    '''Command for START button'''

    global PAUSE

    PAUSE = False
    start_button['state'] = 'disabled'
    pause_button['state'] = 'normal'
    reset_button['state'] = 'normal'
    # time.sleep(1) to delay time between clicks of pause and start buttons
    Counter()


def pause():
    '''Command for PAUSE button'''

    global PAUSE

    PAUSE = True
    start_button['state'] = 'normal'
    pause_button['state'] = 'disabled'


def reset():
    '''Command for RESET button'''

    global HOUR, MINUTE, SECOND, PAUSE

    PAUSE = True
    start_button['state'] = 'normal'
    pause_button['state'] = 'disabled'
    reset_button['state'] = 'disabled'
    Time['text'] = '00:00:00'

    HOUR, MINUTE, SECOND = 0, 0, 0


def Counter():
    '''Updating hour, minute and seconds'''

    global HOUR, MINUTE, SECOND

    if PAUSE is False:
        if SECOND == 59:
            if MINUTE == SECOND == 59:
                HOUR += 1

            if MINUTE == 59:
                MINUTE = 0

            else:
                MINUTE += 1

            SECOND = -1

        SECOND += 1

        Time.config(text='{}:{}:{}'.format(str(HOUR).zfill(2), str(MINUTE).zfill(2), str(SECOND).zfill(2)))
        root.after(1000, Counter)


root = Tk()
root.title('COUNTER')

width, height = 342, 108
pos_x = root.winfo_screenwidth() // 2 - width // 2
pos_y = root.winfo_screenheight() // 2 - height // 2

root.geometry('{}x{}+{}+{}'.format(width, height, pos_x, pos_y))

Time = Label(root, fg='Black', text='00:00:00', font=("Helvetica", 40))
Time.pack(side='bottom')

start_button = Button(root, text='START', font=("Arial", 16), fg='black', width=8, command=start)
start_button.pack(side='left')

pause_button = Button(root, text='PAUSE', font=("Arial", 16), fg='black', width=8, state='disabled', command=pause)
pause_button.pack(side='left')

reset_button = Button(root, text='RESET', font=("Arial", 16), fg='black', width=10, state='disabled', command=reset)
reset_button.pack(side='left', fill='both')

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> At first I thought clicking quickly between start and pause buttons speeds the seconds so I added time.sleep(1) to delay click between the buttons which didn't worked.

The problem is that because there is a delay before the `.aftert()` method calls back on itself, hit the start Button multiple times and create multiple loops of the `.after(1000, counter)`. meaning there are many `.after()` loops happening at once. To fix this you just need to make it so then the start button cannot be pressed if there is a `.after()` loop going on.

To do this you must change three of your functions

> The `counter()` function

I have changed the code so then if the counter is running, then the `start_button` will be disabled, and when the counter stops running its state will be back to normal

```py
def Counter():
    '''Updating hour, minute and seconds'''
    global HOUR, MINUTE, SECOND

    if PAUSE is False:
        start_button['state'] = 'disabled' # setting it to disabled if the counter is running
        if SECOND == 59:
            if MINUTE == SECOND == 59:
                HOUR += 1

            if MINUTE == 59:
                MINUTE = 0

            else:
                MINUTE += 1

            SECOND = -1

        SECOND += 1

        Time.config(text='{}:{}:{}'.format(str(HOUR).zfill(2), str(MINUTE).zfill(2), str(SECOND).zfill(2)))
        root.after(1000, Counter)
    else:
        start_button['state'] = 'normal' # setting it to normal if the counter stops
```

> The `pause()` and `reset()` functions

You must remove the ability to set the state of the `start_button` to normal, because this will allow the `start_button` to be pressed before the last counter loop finished

```py
def pause():
    '''Command for PAUSE button'''

    global PAUSE

    PAUSE = True
    pause_button['state'] = 'disabled'

def reset():
    '''Command for RESET button'''

    global HOUR, MINUTE, SECOND, PAUSE

    PAUSE = True
    pause_button['state'] = 'disabled'
    reset_button['state'] = 'disabled'
    Time['text'] = '00:00:00'

    HOUR, MINUTE, SECOND = 0, 0, 0
```

Updating these functions will remove this bug.
Hope this is the answer you were looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `Counter` function calls `root.after(1000,Counter)` each click and also modify the `Time` label instant upon clicking. When you click the buttons quick enough, you can schedule multiple `root.after` and also add up the seconds.

To modify your current script, you can keep track on the current action, and call `root.after_cancel` to pause the action.

```
from tkinter import *

PAUSE = False
HOUR, MINUTE, SECOND = 0, 0, 0
action = None #keep track on current action and also avoid click spam


def start():
    '''Command for START button'''

    global PAUSE, action

    PAUSE = False
    ...
    if not action:
        Counter()


def pause():
    '''Command for PAUSE button'''

    global PAUSE, action

    ...
    if action:
        root.after_cancel(action)
        action = None


def reset():
    '''Command for RESET button'''

    global HOUR, MINUTE, SECOND, PAUSE, action

    ...

    HOUR, MINUTE, SECOND = 0, 0, 0
    action = None


def Counter():
    '''Updating hour, minute and seconds'''

    global HOUR, MINUTE, SECOND, action

    if PAUSE is False:
        if SECOND == 59:
            if MINUTE == SECOND == 59:
                HOUR += 1

            if MINUTE == 59:
                MINUTE = 0

            else:
                MINUTE += 1

            SECOND = -1

        SECOND += 1

        Time.config(text='{}:{}:{}'.format(str(HOUR).zfill(2), str(MINUTE).zfill(2), str(SECOND).zfill(2)))
        action = root.after(1000, Counter)

root = Tk()
...
start_button = Button(root, text='START', font=("Arial", 16), fg='black', width=8, command=lambda: root.after(1000,start)) #to avoid the instant second increment
```